# Is it possible to retrieve data from Google sheets to my web site to autofill an existing form in my laravel web site

Tags: php, laravel, google-sheets, manychats

I'm Creating a Whatsapp chatbot using ManyChat (chatbot builder) and I will store user inputs from the chat to Google sheets and then later I want to import this data to auto fill an existing form in my web site.

My website is built with Laravel.

Comment: Sure, it's possible; Sheets has an API.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If possible, this package has an easy integration with laravel and google sheet. [laravel-google-sheets](https://github.com/kawax/laravel-google-sheets)